# printf not yielding input values

Tags: c, printf, scanf, format-specifiers

I have the following block of code. The final line is meant to yield the values for `X`,`Y` and `P` values that are input by the user. However it only returns

> (0,0,0)

instead of the values given by user. What am I missing?

```
printf("What is the robot's initial X position? (cm)\n");
scanf("%f",&X);
printf("What is the robot's initial Y position? (cm)\n");
scanf("%f",&Y);
printf("What is the robot's initial angular position? (degrees)\n");
scanf("%f",&P);
printf("The initial position is (%d, %d, %d)\n", X,Y,P);
```

Comment: what exactly is `PrintF`???

Comment: @SouravGhosh Just edited my title, meant to say 'printf'

Comment: You're scanning X, Y and P as `double`s, but printing them as `int`s, what is their type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `X`, `Y` and `P` are of type `double` or `float` (*input part*, `scanf()`), you need to use `%f` or `%lf` format specifier (as required) to print (or scan) the values.

- For printing `float` or `double`, you need to use `%f`
- For scanning `float`, use `%f`, for scanning double, use `%lf`.

Using wrong type of argument for a particular format specifier is[undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). `%d` expects an `int` argument. So, in your case, using `%d` for `float` or `double` type of argument is  UB.

Comment: No problems then caused by not-yet consumed returns?

Comment: @Jongware Did not get you. returns (leading whitespace) in case of `%f` is anyway ignored, right?

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested, `C11`, §7.21.6.2/8

Comment: sorry @SouravGhosh, I wouldn't really know. It was sort of educated guess because it's a common mistake when using `scanf`. But I have such a dislike for `scanf` that I never bothered to memorize all of its ... *eccentricities*, and I've always rolled my own input parsers.

Comment: @Jongware It's ok, I also prefer `fgets()` and `strtok()` over `scanf()` most of the time but somehow bugged so many times by `scanf()` that it's pitfalls are almost _memorized_. :-)